# Ansible command using variable input fails to execute

Tags: ansible

Below I'm trying to get a command running involving input from previous output, in this case `copy flash:file01 flash:file02` with `2` derived from the REGEX_FILTERING task.

```
- name: REGEX_FILTERING
  command: "cat /home/ubuntu/show_switch.txt"
  register: line1
- debug: var="{{ line1.stdout_lines | regex_replace('(?<!\*).?') }}"
  register: number

- name: COMMAND_INPUT
  cli_command:
         command: 'copy flash:file01 flash:file0 {{ number }}'
         prompt: '[confirm]'
         answer: ''
```

Here's the error message:

```
<ommited>
 "stdout_lines": [
        "Switch/Stack Mac Address : d4a0.2ae9.ec00",
        "                                           H/W   Current",
        "----------------------------------------------------------",
        " 1       Member 001f.9df6.2d80     5      0       Ready               ",
        "*2       Master d4a0.2ae9.ec00     15     0       Ready               ",
        " 3       Member 0016.c733.cd00     5      0       Ready"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ubuntu/test1.yml:109
ok: [CSR1] => {
    "2": "2"
}

TASK [COMMAND_INPUT] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ubuntu/test1.yml:112
<192.168.255.133> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu
<192.168.255.133> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-7528uUJSLh/ansible-tmp-1542986468.48-164922344690120 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1542986468.48-164922344690120="` echo /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-7528uUJSLh/ansible-tmp-1542986468.48-164922344690120 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/network/cli/cli_command.py
<192.168.255.133> PUT /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-7528uUJSLh/tmpkozHVx TO /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-7528uUJSLh/ansible-tmp-1542986468.48-164922344690120/AnsiballZ_cli_command.py
<192.168.255.133> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-7528uUJSLh/ansible-tmp-1542986468.48-164922344690120/ /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-7528uUJSLh/ansible-tmp-1542986468.48-164922344690120/AnsiballZ_cli_command.py && sleep 0'
<192.168.255.133> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-7528uUJSLh/ansible-tmp-1542986468.48-164922344690120/AnsiballZ_cli_command.py && sleep 0'
<192.168.255.133> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-7528uUJSLh/ansible-tmp-1542986468.48-164922344690120/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_cli_command_payload_U1p385/__main__.py", line 150, in main
    response = connection.get(**module.params)
  File "/tmp/ansible_cli_command_payload_U1p385/ansible_cli_command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/connection.py", line 173, in __rpc__
    raise ConnectionError(to_text(msg, errors='surrogate_then_replace'), code=code)

fatal: [CSR1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "answer": [
                ""
            ],
            "check_all": false,
            "command": "copy flash:file01 flash:file0 {'failed': False, u'2': u'2', 'changed': False}",
            "prompt": [
                "[confirm]"
            ],
            "sendonly": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "copy flash:file01 flash:file0 {'failed': False, u'2': u'2', 'changed': False}\r\n                                   ^\r\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\r\n\r\nCSR1#\r\nCSR1#"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `"command": "copy flash:file01 flash:file0 {'failed': False, u'2': u'2', 'changed': False}",`

Is happening because the `register: number` is not in fact the number, rather it's the ansible result of the `debug:` output. Since `number` is a python `dict`, when it is injected into your command, it is just serialized as if `str()` were called upon the `dict`

It is far more likely that what you want is to capture that variable locally in the task, to make it *just* be the result of the jinja2 expression, and not the result of an ansible task:

```
- cli_command:
     command: 'copy flash:file01 flash:file0 {{ number }}'
  vars:
     number: "{{ line1.stdout_lines | regex_replace('(?<!\*).?') }}"
```

I also suspect you will be happier with `line1.stdout`, which is a `str` of the entire output, versus `line1.stdout_lines` which is a `list` of `str`, making the `regex_replace` on a `list` kind of weird -- I'm surprised it actually even let you do that, to be honest

Comment: Thanks Matthew!
I tried it and some syntax error occurred. 
   - name: COMMAND_INPUT
      ios_command:
        commands:
             command: 'copy flash:file01 flash:file0 {{ apple }}'
             prompt: '[confirm]'
             answer: ''
      vars:
        apple: "{{ line1.stdout | regex_replace('(?<!\*).?') }}"

Comment: ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unknown escape character

The error appears to have been in '/home/ubuntu/test1.yml': line 119, column 54, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

      vars:
        apple: "{{ line1.stdout | regex_replace('(?<!\*).?') }}"
                                                     ^ here

Comment: I would bet it's because of the backslash inside double-quotes, in which yaml will expand backslashes; you can use regex "character classes" to effectively quote the asterisk without getting into the backslash business: `regex_replace('(?<![*]).?')` type deal

Comment: In the future, have some decency and use code formatting for your code snippets

Comment: Perfect! It works now. Appreciate your help! And got your point with formatting, I will do.